# Laravel send activation link to a specific email

Tags: php, laravel

I want the activation link after registration to send to one email, this because I don't want everyone to create an admin account, so anyone create an admin account the owner of the app will activate his account by clicking on the activation link on his email (the owner email).

```php
protected function postAdminRegistration(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    try {
        $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt(array_get($validatedData, 'password'));
        $validatedData['activation_code'] = str_random(30).time();
        $user = app(User::class)->create($validatedData);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        logger()->error($exception);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Unable to create new user.');
    }
    $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));

    return redirect()->route("user.loginform")->withSuccess('Successfully created a new account.
        Please check your email and activate your account.');
}
```

**UserRegisteredSuccessfully**

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $user = $this->user;

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->from('****@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Successfully created new account')
        ->greeting(sprintf('Hello %s', $user->fname))
        ->line('You have successfully registered to our system. Please activate your account.')
        ->action('Click Here',
            route('user.activate', $user->activation_code))->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
protected $fillable = [
'name','email','password'
];

protected static $logFillable = true;
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
$this->notify(new ResetPassword($token.'/'.$this->email));
}
}
```

Comment: you mean to send the activation link to specific email? then you have to add this email

Comment: where I have to put this email? after  ->from('****@gmail.com')?

Comment: I think this is the only way you can get the email

Comment: any update please?

Comment: @FaragHalain To whom you want to send the activation email( To the `owner of the app` or to the ` registered user`)?

Comment: to a specific email, let say to fixedemail@example.com this email will not change for any new admin wants to register so the activate link will always be send to fixedemail@example.com

Answer (score 1):

add to method in your code

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->from('****@gmail.com')
    ->to("xyz@email.com")

     ...
```

for more details https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications

Comment: can you explain more? where have to add this? if after from then this will not work...Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::to()

Comment: ,added the model, check please

Comment: I need a solution for my case please, what you sent I've seen before and don't know if it is applicable for my case so just write a code here if possible thnkx

Comment: send mail using mailables https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables

Answer (score 0):

Can't add a comment, so i post the possible answer this way; i assume you can add the recipient by
`->to('someone@somewhere.not')`

Comment: can you explain more? where have to add this? if after from then this will not work...Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::to()

Comment: unfortunately didn't find answer